# CURLOPT_URL how to get two different links?

Tags: php, curl

The below code works with API URL: https://api2.example.com/service/vps/list

but the API provider has changed, they use 2 URLs at the same time, for example: https://api2.example.com/service/vps/list and https://api2.example.com/service/dedicated/list

how to get vps and dedicated information from the above two links?

this is my code working with https://api2.example.com/service/vps/list only:

```
if (!defined("WHMCS"))
    die("This file cannot be accessed directly");

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class FKL
{

    public $apikey = '';
    public $apiurl = 'https://api2.example.com/';

    public function __construct($apikey = '')
    {
        $this->apikey = $apikey;
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        $sendparams = [];
        $sendparams['APIKey'] = $this->apikey;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiurl . "service/vps/list");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($sendparams, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json')
        );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($result) {
            $list = json_decode($result, true);
            return $list['data'];
        }
    }

    public function getOSList()
    {
        $sendparams = [];
        $sendparams['APIKey'] = $this->apikey;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiurl . "service/vps/os");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($sendparams, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json')
        );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($result) {
            $list = json_decode($result, true);
            return $list['data'];
        }
    }
......
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain why simply adding a new method in a similar format while changing the URL slightly doesn't meet your requirements...? Where are you getting stuck here?

Comment: actually I don't understand anything about PHP, can you give me an example? thank you

Comment: How did you write this code if you "*don't understand anything about PHP*"? Copying the function definitions and changing the URL to which the cURL operation reaches out to the newly-provided API endpoint would be the path of least resistance. To be honest, I'm not sure how to express it clearer than that.

Comment: If you want to call two URLs, then make the code run two requests. Currently you run one request, so you can more-or-less just duplicate this code to make it run the second request.

Answer (score 0):

I have added code:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiurl . "service/dedicated/list");
```

bellow:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiurl . "service/vps/list");
```

and now are working!